# spam and spammers filter feature request

Tags: feature-request

I do not know what are the merits of downvoting except to discourage newcomers and appaling from continuation of discussion, but, IMO, it does not have sense without filtering users feature(s).

Some users are continuously chasing my posts just to insert off-topic comments, mostly the same.

How would I block some of the user's postings cluttering my view?

I'd like to see in SF the feature permitting to prohibit certain users from accessing my posts (viewing, editing, commenting, answering).

Comment: What you are talking about is not SPAM.  The system handles SPAM very well.

Answer (score 4):

From the FAQ:

> Like Wikipedia, this site is collaboratively edited, and all edits are tracked. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your questions and answers being edited by other trusted users, **this may not be the site for you.**

I don't quite understand why you are making such attempts to turn this site into exactly what you desire instead of finding a site that already runs in a way that is tolerable of your behavior. The interwebz is very large. I'm sure you can find a place to call ~.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to take SE feature requests to MSO.  But I don't think this one is going to work out much better than the last time [it was discussed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users).

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of voting is describe in the tool tips.

- Question upvote: This question is useful and clear
- Question downvote: This question is unclear or not useful
- Answer upvoate: This answer is useful
- Answer downvote: This answer is not useful

When you receive a downvote you should evaluate your Question or answer.

- Downvotes on questions

  - Make sure it is easy to read and understandable.
  - Make sure your your post has a single main question. You can add a couple extra questions that support your the primary question.  But your post should cover a single issue or topic.
  - Check that what you have posted is on-topic.
  - Clearly related to system administration, networking, and support of many desktops.
  - Make sure your question has not already been asked.
  - Make sure your question not argumentative.
  - This is not a place to argue Microsoft vs Linux vs Apple
  - Make sure your question is not subjective
  - Avoid asking questions like `what is the best ...`
- Downvotes on answers

  - It must be technically correct
  - Make sure it is easy to read and understandable.
  - Make sure you directly address the question that was asked.
  - You can bring up related issues, but if you do not address the main question, then what you have posted isn't really an answer.
- Do not include be rude or impolite comments in your question/answer/comments.  Even if you strongly disagree with some comment or answer. Do not respond with insults.  Do not try to treat SF like a typical forum/newsgroup.